# How to Optimize Data Importing to a Django Model using django-import-export library

Tags: django, django-models, data-import, bulk-load, django-import-export

I have been using django-import-export library to upload my data as excel to the Django model and it has been working fine till i had to Upload an excel with 20,000 rows and it just took infinite time to get this action done.

Can you please suggest the right way to optimize data Uploading to the Django model, where i can easily upload excel files and have that data saved in my Database.

Please support.

Hi below is the code for admin.py that i tried, but its throwing error 'using_transactions' is not defined, please confirm where am i going wrong and what do i change to get bulk data imported in less time--

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export import resources
from .models import Station,Customer
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

# Register your models here.

class StationResource(resources.ModelResource):

    def get_or_init_instance(self,instance_loader,row):
        self.bulk_create(self, using_transactions, dry_run, raise_errors, 
        batch_size=1000)

    class Meta:
        model=Station
        use_bulk=True
        batch_size = 1000
        force_init_instance = True


class StationAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
        resource_class=StationResource

admin.site.register(Station , StationAdmin)
```

and in the settings.py file i have set-

```
IMPORT_EXPORT_USE_TRANSACTIONS = True
IMPORT_EXPORT_SKIP_ADMIN_LOG = True
```

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 1):

import-export provides a [bulk import](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bulk_import.html) mode which makes use of Django's [bulk operations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create).

Simply enable the `use_bulk` flag on your resource:

```py
 class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'author_email', 'price')
        use_bulk = True
```

It should be possible to import 20k rows in a few seconds, but it will depend on your data and you may need to tweak some settings.  Also, do read the [caveats](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bulk_import.html#caveats) regarding bulk imports.

There is [more detailed information](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/tree/e855fcf8ed43af4dd681435f516e9f50ee19613d/tests/bulk) in the repo.

However, even without bulk mode it should be able to import 20k rows in a few minutes.  If it is taking much longer, then it is possible that the import process is making unnecessary reads on the db (i.e for each row).  Enabling SQL logging will shed some light on this.  [`CachedInstanceLoader`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_instance_loaders.html#import_export.instance_loaders.CachedInstanceLoader) may help with this.

Comment: Hi, i checked out the resources that you shared and i tried to modify the admin.py, still not very sure what all do i need to add further or delete. Adding the code from admin.py in the next comment, please support. What exactly do i need to change to be abel to import data in less time.

Comment: Hi, i have shared my code above, please check and support.

Comment: I suggest study the documentation and source (if necessary) and figure out what your code is doing.  The way you have it now it will attempt to do a bulk create at the point it tries to read each row which is completely wrong.  Understanding what your code is doing will save you a mountain of time in the long run.

Answer (score -2):

I wouldn't use import-export for large data,
instead, I'd save the data file as csv from my excel file and use pandas to bridge the data into the database. Pandas does it in batches.

Comment: Does that work fine? How about the admin integration and does it work well if you have to keep.changing the data. Can you please share an example for that.  Have been stuck on this issue since long and need to find a doable solution for this.